# Symfony 4 error: Compile Error: Cannot declare class, because the name is already in use

Tags: php, symfony

When I updated from Symfony 3.4 to Symfony 4 and displayed the system with a browser, the following error appeared.
When I raised it to 4, I abolished the two bundles and moved them to `src/`. Of course, there is no same service.php.
I also did `composer dump-autoload`. Is there anything else to consider?

**Error Code**

```
Compile Error: Cannot declare class App\Model\Service\EcItemTagService, because the name is already in use
```

**Code**
services.yaml

```yaml
  App\:
    resource: '../src/*'
    exclude: '../src/{Entity, Migrations, Tests}'

  common.ecItemTagService:
     class: App\Model\Service\EcItemTagService
     arguments: ['@service_container']
```

**Version**
PHP 7.3
Symfony4.0.9

Answer (score -1):

Remove this line, then you can use `EcItemTagService` directly with his full namespace

```
common.ecItemTagService:
 class: App\Model\Service\EcItemTagService
 arguments: ['@service_container']
```

The error is raised because you are using autowiring for all services inside 'src'

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to use ```common.ecItemTagService``` as it is because there are many modifications?

Comment: You have to exclude it from the autowiring. But with flex, many of your service configuration will not be needed anymore. Don't worry about many modification